# SSRS Multi Value Parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, reportingservices-2005

I have a report having two tab-lix and also two data set(e.g=dataset1,dataset2) for each tab-lix. When i am generating report by passing the multiple parameter location id(38,39 & 40) value if there is no record of id-38 in dataset2 i want blank space but in my report it is showing report of 39. But i want if there is no data in data set based on the parameter it is showing only blank space.Because always dataset1 having data and so it showing properly.When i am generating report with multiple parameter(38,39,40) it showing tablix1 of 38 parameter but tablix2 of 39 parameter in on page because of there is no data in dataset2 of 38 parameter.So i want to display a blank space on behalf of tablix2 if there is no data.

Give me a solution.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO!



Please [edit] your question to clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Do you have any code?

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes you have a table that contains all locations e.g. `DimLocations`, if not you should consider creating one.

You can then change your dataset query to be something like.

```
SELECT loc.LocationID, t.SomeColumn, t.AnotherColumn
    FROM DimLocations loc
        LEFT JOIN myTable t ON loc.LocationID = t.LocationID
    WHERE loc.LocationID IN(@myLocationParameter)
```

This will ensure that you get a record for each location as long as it appears in the `DimLocations` table.

If this does not help, edit your question to show the dataset query you are using now and the structure of your locations table (if you have one)